# Actualizar ciertos campos dependiendo una cantidad

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreach

estoy trabajando con una tabla de ordenes, y necesito guardar ciertos valores depiendo una cantidad, explicare

```
Tabla ordenes
 id | sku | nombre    | cantidad | costo_unidad | total
 -----------------
 1  | A1  | articulo 1| 3        |              |
 2  | A1  | articulo 2| 1        |              |
```

Tengo una vista donde muestro la SUMA de las cantidades de las ordenes que tiene el mismo SKU
como ejemplo de la tabla que serian 4
y en mi vista muestro un solo card con la informacion y que necesito comprar 4 articulos

Entonces en mi formulario tengo 2 campos ,
'cantidad' y 'precio'

y si ingreso que compre 3 a 100 pesos necesito que se actualice el precio unitario pero de solo un campo
porque solo compre 3

```
 Tabla ordenes
 id | sku | nombre    | cantidad | costo_unidad | total
 -----------------
 1  | A1  | articulo 1| 3        |    1000      | 300
 2  | A1  | articulo 2| 1        |              |
```

Pero si compro 4 a 100 pesos que se actualice el siguiente y quede de la siguiente manera

```
Tabla ordenes
 id | sku | nombre    | cantidad | costo_unidad | total
 -----------------
 1  | A1  | articulo 1| 3        |    100       | 300
 2  | A1  | articulo 2| 1        |    100       | 100
```

Necesito ir guardando esa información dependiendo la cantidad pedida por cada orden

este es mi guardado por ahora

```
 $ordenes=Orden::select(Orden::raw('sum(cantidad) as total, sku'))
    ->where('comprado','')
    ->orWhere('comprado',null)
    ->groupBy('sku')
    ->get();

    $producto= Orden::where('sku',$sku)
    ->get();
    foreach ($producto as $key => $value) {
        $ca=$request->cantidad -  $value->cantidad;;
          

                $producto =Orden::where('sku',$sku)
                ->update([
                    'comprado'=>'si',   
                    'costo_unitario'=>$ca,
                ]);  
        
    }
```

La variable ordenes me muestra la suma de las cantidad por sku

y producto me retorna lo mismo pero con todos los campos,

Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

Comment: Y qué esperas que pase si sólo ingresa que compró 2? A qué fila piensas restarle?

Comment: Lo tengo contemplado, agregando un campo extra de pendientes